# Looking for a natural phrase to the following context

Tags: phrases

I have a friend of mine who promised me to do some task, but at the end of the day, the time wasn't enough for him to complete the task. He sent me messages of which he says that he's really sorry. I want to make him relax and comfort, what's the best way to phrase it?

"Feel comfort, it's ok, you can do it later when you have time" OR "Feel convenience, it's ok, you can do it later" Or maybe other better natural phrases?

Comment: You say he obligated _you_ to do the task, but the rest of your paragraph implies that _he_ was supposed to do it, so I'm puzzled. Anyway, to reassure him you could say "Never mind" or "Don't worry" - certainly _not_ "Feel convenience".

Comment: Well, my wording wasn't the best at this time, I changed this word to make it clear. Are there not phrases which contain direct words for relaxation / comfort / convenience etc.?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could say "Relax" or "Take it easy", but I don't think convenience is appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'feel better. Everything will be fine. You can do it later.' or something along those lines would be good because it would be telling him to not worry (Don't worry is another possibility for the first sentence) and it would also tell him that it does not affect anything major in the long run of his project/task or in your relationship. The phrases 'feel comfort' and 'feel convenience' are not used very commonly in English because they are not idiomatically correct.